# error using scalatest, sbt directory structure

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a project using the sbt project structure. Until yesterday everything was in `src/main/scala` but now I added some tests using scalatest and put it into `src/test/scala`.

Here's the related code (using slick 3) in `src/main/scala/SomeTables.scala`:

```
package com.slicktest

import slick.driver.HsqldbDriver.api._

case class MyData(id: Int, my_double: Double)

class MyTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[MyData](tag, "Test_Table") {
  def id = column[Int]("ID_Test", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def my_column = column[Double](myTable.my_value)
  def * = (id, my_column) <> ((MyData.apply _).tupled, MyData.unapply)
}
object myTable extends TableQuery(new MyTable(_)) {
  var my_value = ""
}
```

If I compile only the files in `src/main/scala` it works fine, but when I also want to compile the test files (running `sbt test`) in `src/test/scala` it prints the following error message:

```
Error:scalac: error while loading MyTable, class file 'C:\...\target\scala-2.11\classes\com\slicktest\MyTable.class' has location not matching its contents: contains class com.slicktest.myTable
```

What's the problem here and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `myTable` to `MyTable` (as companion object should be named anyway) - I think that compiler tries to create `MyTable.class` and `myTable.class` and on Windows names are case insensitive. So you override one file with another.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that you have a similar Class name available in your project directory , which is making a conflict. You can try by changing the class name and see if it fixes the problem .